# Moved one site to another site files are refering old site

Tags: migrations, multi-sites, configuration, xml-sitemap

I moved whole Drupal setup from ex.(1.1.1.1 to www.example.com). After the move there are some issues. Some Drupal default files are not found error.(ex. close.png ,background.png) because the images references are for the old url:  http://1.1.1.1/modules/overlay/images/background.png.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

First clear all caches. If that does not resolve the issue check your settings.php file(s) for references to the old address.

If you have images in content you can search the database tables for those fields to look for references (but fix them through Drupal's interface). Unless you have a huge number your better off fixing those one by one. Generally in D7 and before you want site or page relative image references not absolute references.

Comment: after moved whole setup i changed base_url as new site address.but still its not working

Comment: And you cleared the site caches and your browser cache?

Comment: yeah cleared all caches

Comment: Are these missing images referenced in content area? or in the Theme?

Comment: i think content area.